# Resources to learn : Javascript prototype object model?

Tags: prototype, javascript

I am pretty new to `in-depth` `javascript`.

Now, since I come from the world of `C/C++ or Java` type classes - I find it new.

The problem is :

- When I search for resources for `Javascript Prototype Object`, I end up with `prototypejs`
- [ProtoTypeJs](http://prototypejs.org/) - Its a js library just like `jQuery`
- PrototypeJS : AFAIK it makes javascript classes just like `Java` type classes.

In a nutshell, its keeping me from learning javascript object model. :P

Can you provide some resources i.e `Videos` or `articles` or `ebooks` that teaches `Javascript Prototype Object Model` ?

Comment: Please see [Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)

Comment: `SO` seems to be the only place to ask this. We need a `SO social network` may be.

Comment: It's called "[chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)".

Comment: Chat needs to be around a Question in present `SO`. But you want to close the question. Apart from that `SO Open Chat` could be a good option - Which we don't have right now (AFAIK).

Comment: Chat does **not** need to be around a question (that is optional). There are [plenty of general topic rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active).

Comment: Ohk.. didn't knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the best i've come across for a beginner is

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#a-prototype-chain

You can also go through ECMA specification for getting a clear picture